# Testing Facades, Is it a good idea?

Tags: unit-testing

I stumbled across a need to create a thin I/O Layer interface to abstract away a class from the need to know about I/O

```
public interface IFileIOProvider {
    Task WriteFileAsync(String contents, String path);
    Task<String> ReadFileAsync(String path);
}
```

Is it a good idea to test a default implementation that *only* falls back to standard .Net System.IO classes, no logic attached?. I think it might be overkill, but just want to get my strategy checked out by more experienced programmers

Comment: You don't have the luxury of testing everything; test the things that have a meaningful chance of being wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this should be tested by system/acceptance tests that cover what ever feature needs this class

for unit tests I'd say the answer is mostly no, there is nothing useful to test here, the only time I would unit test is if it was more effort to justify why I'm not testing this class than to test it (sometimes the case with safety related stuff)